# Split continuous variable into equal size groups

Tags: r, split, cut, bin

I have a continous variable `Total_testscore`. I have split it in 4 groups, but they are not of equal sample size. How can I split the variable such that the resulting levels of the variable are of the same sample size?

```
> mydata$Total_testscore_f <- cut(mydata$Total_testscore, breaks = 4)
> table(mydata$Total_testscore_f)

(1.99,5.5]    (5.5,9]   (9,12.5]  (12.5,16] 
        25        116         95         50
```

Comment: We need some data in order to help you. However, you can check function `ntile` from `dplyr` package. Some more info here: https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/BurStMisc/versions/1.1/topics/ntile

Comment: One approach would be to sort the data and then to split by length.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `quantile()` function to get the required breaks.  Example:

```
> x <- rnorm(100) # replace with your real data
> table(cut(x, breaks = quantile(x, seq(0, 1, l=5)), include.lowest = TRUE))

 [-2.07,-0.756] (-0.756,0.0664]  (0.0664,0.963]    (0.963,2.83] 
             25              25              25              25
```

Comment: well, the breaks are not of equal sample size in that case:   `(2,7]  (7,10] (10,12] (12,16] 
     73     104      58      50 `

Comment: @user1607 Does your data have duplicate values?  If you have, say, `x <- c(0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2)`, then all the `1` will end up in the same group, so there is no way for the groups to be of equal size.  Maybe your situation is similar?